# HTML multi submitting with same value in a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to send request to my server through HTML multiple submitting request with same value in a loop how can i do that here my HTML doc

```js
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

```html
<form method="Post" action="http://Myserver/WebPage">
  Enter The Request:
  <input name="requestcode" type="text" Value="0017105685" />
  <input type="submit" Vlue="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. You need to use Ajax with the next call in the success

Each submit will reload the page, killing your script.

So for example, using jQuery (for speed of coding) - you could use fetch instead

```js
const ids = ["1", "2"];
let cnt = 0

function postIt() {
  $.post("http://Myserver/WebPage", {
    requestcode: "0017105685",
    id: ids[cnt]
  }, function() {
    cnt++;
    if (cnt < ids.length) postIt(); // continue until end of ids array
  })
}
$(function() {
  postIt();
})
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a useful comment. What happens. Errors in console? Server errors? What does "does not work" mean here?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response I think we declare a string value named  "requestcode" in the server so the server accept this string as a prameter which in this case has a value "0017105685"

Comment: it's working fine now thank you it was helpful but i need to ask how can i send id for each request with same value but different id number to allow the server distinguished between each request such as requestcode 0017105685 with id = 1  server send email to group 1 , id =2 send email to group 2 and so on